How to sort a dictionary by using len() function
This is a dictionary I have:
mydict = {
    4: {'K', 'H'},
    2: {'Y', 'X', 'Q', 'U'},
    8: {'A', 'T', 'S'},
}

It seems there are some ways to sort a dictionary that I tried but didn't work:
sorted([(value,key) for (key,value) in mydict.items()])

But I'm going to sort using the len() function based on how many values does it each has.
This is the current len() output:
for x in mydict: print(x, mydict[x], len(mydict[x]))

How can I sort the dictionary as expected?
Expected output would be:
mydict = {
    2: {'Y', 'X', 'Q', 'U'},
    8: {'A', 'T', 'S'},
    4: {'K', 'H'},
}


Why do you want to sort a dictionary? If order matters to you, chances are you should use another data structure, e.g. a plain list.

@Julien because the dictionary is what I have, and I cannot change it to list. If I change, I should add more new lines and I don't think it's good

Since dictionaries in Python 3.7+ maintain insertion order (was implementation detail in Python 3.6), you can rebuild the dictionary in the correct order after sorting:
my_dict = {
    4: {'K', 'H'},
    2: {'Y', 'X', 'Q', 'U'},
    8: {'A', 'T', 'S'},
}

sorted_dict = dict(
    sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]), reverse=True))

print(sorted_dict)

Output:
{2: {'Y', 'Q', 'U', 'X'}, 8: {'S', 'A', 'T'}, 4: {'H', 'K'}}

Note: Sets, unlike dictionaries, do not guarantee ordering hence the output values above is expected to be different from yours in that regard (and not necessarily the same every run).
